# Start to monitor location updates with locationManager from Apple Watch while the iPhone app is in background

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, core-location, apple-watch

I'm working on a very simple GPS-based app where users can monitor their driving. Typically, this is what a user-driver does :

- go in his/her car
- launch the app
- press a button that says "I'm driving"
- drive
- press a "I'm arrived" button when arrived to his/her destination

I want the Apple Watch companion app where I would find these two buttons. So there are two scenarios :

- A/ When the app is in **foreground**, there are no problems.
- B/ When the app is in **background or not started** though, I don't get any gps updates. Nothing happens. Nada.

Here's some code.

When user pressed the "I'm driving" button on the watch and the app is not started in the simulator :

```
// Regular location manager
self.standardLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.standardLocationManager.delegate = self;
self.standardLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = self.accuracy;
self.standardLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
self.standardLocationManager.distanceFilter = self.distanceFilter;
[self.standardLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

// Significant Location Change location manager
self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager.delegate = self;
self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager.activityType = CLActivityTypeAutomotiveNavigation;
[self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

// Start the managers
[self.standardLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

I'm using [MWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) to "debug" what is happening.

The only called delegate method is :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways){
        if (manager == self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager) {
            [[WatchController sharedController]notify:@"starting slc loc manager"]; // call MWWormHole to debug
            [self.significantLocationChangeLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        } else if (manager == self.standardLocationManager) {
            [[WatchController sharedController]notify:@"starting standard loc manager"];  // call MWWormHole to debug
            [self.standardLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    }
}
```

In this delegate method, `status` is Authorized because I have both debug message in my watch app.

My questions :

- Is what I want to do even possible in the Apple world ?
- What am I doing wrong ? Am I missing something ?
- Is this post clear enough ?